# Backbone.history.navigate with IE <= 9

Tags: backbone.js

Having an issue with using Backbone history / push state - but only with browsers that don't support it (old IE)

The issue is this. When I visit `/en_gb/dashboard` for the first time - everything works, in all browsers. However, in IE<=9, it's appending `#dashboard` to the address bar, forming `/en_gb/dashboard#dashboard`. Now, when I hit refresh, my router is not triggering.

Not all my site is under Backbone control - so the router is working off:

```
routes: {
  'dashboard': 'showDashboard'
}
```

My bootstrap looks like this:

```
if (Backbone.history) {

  var pushStateSupported = _.isFunction(history.pushState);
  var urlRoot = '/en_gb/';
  var enableSilent = !pushStateSupported;

  Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: pushStateSupported,
    root: urlRoot,
    silent: enableSilent
  });

  if (!pushStateSupported) {
    Backbone.history.navigate(window.location.pathname.substring(urlRoot.length), { trigger: true });
  }
}
```

Adding debug, I can see `Backbone.history.navigate()` always being called but it seems the `trigger: true` is not being picked up when that hash is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - I seem to have fixed it - while not an elegant solution, this does solve it for me:

```
if (!pushStateSupported) {
    var route = window.location.pathname.substring(urlRoot.length);
    Backbone.history.navigate('/#' + route, { trigger: true });
}
```

It's not elegant in that the URL in the address bar appears as `/en_gb/dashboard##dashboard` - but it is now getting through the `Backbone.navigate()` method. Previously it was failing on

```
if (this.fragment === fragment) return;
```